# Converting IST to local time in angular js

Tags: angularjs, timezone, datetime-conversion, datefilter

From server I am getting time in this format "21/11/2017 17:01:30", and this time is in IST. I want to convert this time to the users local time.

I am using below given code for that,

```
var startDateTimeArray = eachExeRun.startDate.split(" ");
var startDateArray = startDateTimeArray[0].split("/");
var startDate = new Date(startDateArray[2]+"-"+startDateArray[1]+"-"+startDateArray[0]+' '+startDateTimeArray[1]);
```

And now my startDate is "**Tue Nov 21 2017 16:59:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**"

In html I used like this

```
{{startDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}
```

After this to test my code I changed my system's timezone to pasific time zone, then my startTime changed to "**Tue Nov 21 2017 16:59:29 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)**", but in my view still its showing "***2017-11-21 16:59:29***".

How can I display updated time without using timezone in date filter(date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z').

Comment: I suggest you use moment.js which is brilliant for date time conversions, very popular library

Comment: MomentJS with [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Using moment.js is the beat way.

However, you could also write a custom filter for converting the dates.

Try this:

```
    app.filter('myFormat', function() {
        return function(x) {
                var startDateTimeArray = x.split(" ");
                var startDateArray = startDateTimeArray[0].split("/");
                var startDate = new Date(startDateArray[2]+"-"+startDateArray[1]+"-"+startDateArray[0]+' '+startDateTimeArray[1]);
                console.log(startDate);
                //from timezone
                var IST_timezone_offset = -330; // IST timezone offset -always known
                var req_UTC_Milliseconds =  (IST_timezone_offset * 60000) ;
                //to timezone
                var local_timezone_offset = startDate.getTimezoneOffset(); 
                var local_UTC_Milliseconds = (local_timezone_offset * 60000);

                var final_date = new Date( startDate.getTime() + (req_UTC_Milliseconds - local_UTC_Milliseconds ) );

                return final_date;
            };
        });
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/k2btc3ds/)

Answer (score 0):

Using momentJs it is quite simple:

Find the working code snippet below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <h2>My IST to Local System Date Convertor</h2>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dateCtrl">
        <p>{{convertIstToSystemLocalDateUsingTimeZone(IstStartDate)}}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('dateCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.IstStartDate = '21/11/2017 17:01:30';
            $scope.convertIstToSystemLocalDateUsingTimeZone = function (incomingISTString) {
                return moment.tz(incomingISTString, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss', 'Asia/Kolkata')
                    .local().format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```